# TIBCO ems Queue limit exceeded

Tags: java, jms, tibco, tibco-ems

I am getting an exception (shown below) when trying to send messages to a TIBCO Ems queue.

```
 javax.jms.ResourceAllocationException: Queue limit exceeded
 at com.tibco.tibjms.Tibjmsx.buildException(Tibjmsx.java:523)
 at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._publish(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:1390)
 at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsMessageProducer._publish(TibjmsMessageProducer.java:246)
 at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueSender.send(TibjmsQueueSender.java:51)
```

The only place I have seen this exception talked about is this link : http://class10e.com/tibco/a-queue-is-defined-as/

And from  here I was able to guess that you are required to have at least one consumer per queue before you send any messages. Once i created a consumer it worked, but only up to about 5 or 6 messages. What is strange is that I empty the queue before every time i test, and I am sending the same exact text messages, so there is no size difference. How come it fails sometimes after 5 and sometimes after 6 messages? I am not consuming the messages after I initially empty the queue (I created a consumer but used eclipses debug to pause the thread of the message consumer). Does anyone know what the cause of this exception is?

Comment: Please post `show queue <YOUR.QUEUE>` results from `tibemsadmin` after getting the exception

Answer (score 2):

Be carefull using

```
setprop queue queue-name maxmsgs=10000

setprop queue queue-name maxbytes=1024MB
```

Setprop removes, ALL the parameters of the queues and replace them with default ones, except that one parameter you are going to change.
If you just want to change one parameter without touching the other ones, use

```
addprop queue queue-name PARAMETER=VALUE
```

`Addprop` adds new parameter or modifies existing one.
if you want to learn more about `setprop` and `addprop` type

```
help setprop

help addprop
```

when logged in to the ems server.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there seems to be MAXBYTES OR MAXMSGS properties set on the destination.Resulting in queue limit exceeded error.

Please check your destination property ..

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to increate queue size form EMS admininistration tool

> setprop queue queue-name maxmsgs=10000
>
> setprop queue queue-name maxbytes=1024MB

Answer (score -1):

this error can be due to following

default size of EMS queue is 512MB if you cross this size then error

Comment: Wrong information, i think user2163769 confuses a default memory setting here (which could easily adjusted), as  Abdul Kader above stated there might be a setting on the destination which could be used to throttle producers to overflow a queue over a threshold, check the MAXBytes or MaxMessages settings on the queue you are trying to use.